# GPU training not starting using yolov8

Tags: yolo, dataloader

I have installed pytorch with gpu activation and then installed ultralytics package in order to run yolov8 on my gpu.  When I start training it shows that the GPU is being used:

> Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.54  Python-3.9.16 torch-2.0.0 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080, 8192MiB)

then after it has prepared the data it shows the following:

> Using 8 dataloader workers

> Logging results to runs\detect\train7

> Starting training for 50 epochs...

and stops.  program keeps running but nothing happens.  I have also created an environment that runs on the cpu which shows a different final line and then starts training:

> Using 0 dataloader workers

> Logging results to runs\detect\train11

> Starting training for 10 epochs...

> Closing dataloader mosaic

Presumably the gpu isn't starting training because it doesn't close the dataloader mosaic, but i do not know how to correct this.  Can anyone help with this?

I have set up the environment in both conda and using pip, with the same result.  I don't get any form of error message when this happens.

Comment: This was solved by specifying the number of workers as 1 when training the model.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by specifying the number of workers as 1 when training the model.
model.train('yolo version used', workers=1)